# Can't install Code::Blocks plugin wxsmith

Tags: package-management, updates, dpkg, code-blocks

I am trying to install wxsmith plugin for codeblocks. I have a running Code::Blocks 13.12 in my computer. This is what I did:

`sudo apt-get install codeblocks-contrib codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev`

It downloaded the plugin but couldn't install it giving me the following error message.

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-contrib_13.12-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/pkgconfig/cb_wximagepanel.pc', which is also in package codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev 13.12-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-contrib_13.12-3_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thank you I resolved this one. The problem seemed the same that the versions were different.

Comment: Thought that gives some idea as what might the problem be, but doesn't exhaustively explain how to do that?

Comment: I first downloaded Code::Blocks and then `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` inside the directory containing the `.deb` files of Code::Blocks only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the same version of `codeblocks-contrib` and `codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev`. This would resolve your issue cleanly, because it looks like the package maintainers decided to move a file from one package to another in between the two versions, which created the conflict you're currently facing.

You appear to have installed those packages with APT, which doesn't resolve the package removal and installation sequence correctly (probably due to incorrect package conflict entries). Therefore you need to download manually and install those packages forcefully:

```
apt-get download codeblocks-contrib codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite --force-overwrite-dir codeblocks-contrib_*.deb codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev_*.deb
```

Alternatively, remove both packages and re-install them:

```
sudo apt-get remove codeblocks-contrib codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev
sudo apt-get install codeblocks-contrib codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev
```

Comment: Removing and reinstalling did the job for me.